# Вывод списка по дате

Tags: php, mysql

Есть таблица, в ней есть столбец дата (ггг-мм-дд) и есть столбец - машина. То есть если человек на странице выбирает дату - 13 марта(без года), то должно выйти список всех машин за 13 марта (не зависимо от года).

Как реализовать в php?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну если на php, то

```
$d = intval($_GET['day']); // $_GET or $_POST
$m = intval($_GET['month']);
```

ну и дальше SQL куда нужно вставить

```
$sql = 'SELECT `filed` FROM `table` WHERE DAYOFMONTH(date) = '.$d.' AND MONTH(date) = '.$m;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
LIKE '%-03-13'
```

Либо

```
DAYOFMONTH(date) = 13 AND MONTH(date) = 3
```

Принципиальной разницы в скорости работы не будет.

Comment: я хотел сказать, что пользователь должен сам выбирать дату вывода